# Identifying row-groups of a rectangular matrix having pairwise orthogonal rows

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition

I have a rectangular matrix `A(m x n, m <= n)` and `A` is full rank. All elements of A are either 1 or 0. If any two rows have a `1` in same column, then they need to be put in same row-group.  As a minimal example;

```
A = [0 0 1 1 0 0
     1 1 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

Then `A` can be decomposed into two row groups `A_1` and `A_2` such that

```
A = [A_1
     A_2]
```

where

```
A_1 = [1 1 0 0 0 0]
A_2 = [0 0 1 1 0 0
       0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

This is because both row vectors of `A_2` are orthogonal to the (only) row vector in `A_1`.

EDIT 1 :

I am adding More Context to hopefully making the problem complete and logical. If it isn't then please let me know.

1) No Solution is not possible.

2) If no such row groups exist, then all the row vectors form a single group.

3) A bigger example to hopefully make things clearer.

```
A = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
```

then there are three row groups containing rows that are pairwise orthogonal to rows from other groups.

```
A_1 = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

A_2 = [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]

A_3 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
```

Please give a link if this is a known concept from Linear Algebra.

Comment: What if $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \end{pmatrix}$ or $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$? What you want generally won't be possible. (Unless you allow empty sets of rows, but then you the answer trivially becomes: "always choose an empty set of rows".)

Comment: if `A=(1)` then A_out = (1), If `A=(1 1;0 1)`, then A_out=[1 1; 0 1]

Comment: That's not a partition of the rows. I don't understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @AlexProvost yes, I just noticed and deleted my reply comment to the same.

Comment: @AlexProvost Yes, I think "partition" is not the right word here as I dont intend to find any blocks. I intend to identify row-groups where, rows from different groups are pairwise orthogonal. I dont know if there is a word this.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to put your problem into some clearer context, specifically under what circumstances no solution is possible.  You have rows (they might as well be points or vectors), some of which are "orthogonal" (or any other symmetric relation) to other rows.  You ask for two subsets such that any pair of rows, one from each subset, are related by "orthogonality".

Comment: @hardmath I have edited problem to hopefully make it clearer. Please let me know if the problem still sounds incomplete or unclear.